# How do I create a list-type thing in Python that has a set size?

Tags: python, list

I tried this:
`mylist = list()`

and did this in an attempt to set the first position of `mylist` to *this* with
`mylist[0] = "this"

However, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    mylist[0] = "this"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range`
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `mylist` is empty. Use `mylist.append("this")` instead.

Comment: Do you *need* it to start with a specified size? Can't you just do `mylist.append("this");`?

Comment: @miradulo: congrats for gold (and good use)